# python spur ssh write sys.stdout to file

Tags: python, ssh, stdout, wx.textctrl

I am using the below code to run a long running command on a remote Windows server via ssh and trying to get the `sys.stdout` and write that to a file in realtime. The below code prints the sys.stdout but does not write it to the file. What am I doing wrong?

```
import wx
import wx.stc as stc
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
import sys
import spur
import subprocess
import threading

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(600, 500), style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & ~ (wx.RESIZE_BORDER | 
                                                wx.RESIZE_BOX | 
                                                wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX))

        self.CreateStatusBar()
        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        menu = wx.Menu()
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)
        self.sshLog1 = sshLog(self)
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

class sshLog(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.frame = self

        self.running_log = wx.TextCtrl(self, pos=(5, 5), size=(570,390))

        self.buttonGo = wx.Button(self, -1, "Go", pos=(180,420))
        self.buttonGo.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Go)
        self.buttonClose = wx.Button(self, -1, "Quit", pos=(285,420))
        self.buttonClose.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClose)
        self.Show()      

    def Go(self, event):
        threading.Thread(target=self.runCommand).start()

    def runCommand(self):
        sys.stdout = open('file.txt', 'w')
        shell = spur.SshShell(hostname='10.1.1.100', username='remoteUsername', password='remotePassword', missing_host_key=spur.ssh.MissingHostKey.accept)
        result = shell.spawn(['ping', 'google.com', '-t'], stdout=sys.stdout)

    def OnClose(self, e):
        CloseApp()

###############################
########## CLOSE APP ##########
###############################
class CloseApp(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(e):
        sys.exit(0)

app = wx.App()
MainWindow(None, -1, 'My App')
app.MainLoop()
```